# R-3.0.2- Win8-64bit: error with installing packages

Tags: r, install.packages

I just started with R. I run a 64bit Windows8 machine.

Here are the commands I have issued and my the responses I got:

```
install.packages("DMwR")
library() #to check if DMwR was installed and it shows up in Packages in library
          ## ‘C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library’

library(DMwR) # THIS IS WHERE I get the error.
```

ERROR MESSAGE:
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘abind’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DMwR’

How can I fix that?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages('abind')`? then `library(DMwR)`. I've had that issue a few times with other packages, but manually installing the dependencies worked for me

Comment: Thanks James for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I followed:

```
 install.packages('abind')
 install.packages('zoo')
 install.packages('xts')
 install.packages('quantmod')
 install.packages('ROCR')
```

and finally:

```
 library(DMwR)
```

Thanks for the help James!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of [@user1561949](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1561949/user1561949) ...
The package `DMwR` contains packages `abind`, `zoo`, `xts`, `quantmod` and `ROCR` as imports. So, additionally to installing 5 packages you must install `DMwR` package:

```
install.packages("DMwR")
```

and than:

```
library(DMwR)
```